# "Out of Band" Ember Data Requests

Tags: ember.js

I have a model I'm exposing via a RESTful API, and this model has state transitions. Events that cause these state transitions (and their side effects) are exposed with this API too. Here's an example of the implementation using Ruby:

```
class Order < AR::B
  # Event of interest
  def complete!
    # do stuff that's interesting
  end
end

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  # e.g. POST /orders/123/complete
  def complete
    @order.complete!
    head :no_content
  end
end
```

What is the best way to call my "complete" end point (POST) using Ember Data? My current approach is to make this an action on a corresponding Ember Controller, but my intuition says this isn't right. I'm open to changing my Ruby implementation as well — I'm not convinced this is the best approach, period.

Comment: I've ended up doing something like this for now: https://gist.github.com/jherdman/10913990